# What's the difference? .on "connect" vs .on "connection"

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm having difficulty understanding the difference between:

```
io.on('connection', function (){ });

io.on('connect', function,(){ });
```

May be quite a primitive question, however I was unable to find clear documentation about it. Would love to learn the difference.

Answer (score 9):

These are different names of the same thing.
As written in `socket.io` [v2 docs](https://socket.io/docs/v2/server-api#event-connect) ([current](https://socket.io/docs/server-api#event-connect)):

> Event: `connection` is synonym of Event: `connect`. Which connect fired upon a connection from client.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with mabe.berlin's idea about the order of these events.

Run:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection',socket.id);
    io.on('connect',function (socket) {
        console.log('conenct',socket.id);
    });
});
http.listen(1111);
```

And you will get something like:

```
connection 6Song1KpSUoUkKgPAAAA
```

But if you try

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connect',function (socket) {
    console.log('conenct',socket.id);
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('connection',socket.id);
    });
});
http.listen(1111);
```

You are supposed to get something like:

```
conenct pSlSKNaabR2LBCujAAAA
connection pSlSKNaabR2LBCujAAAA
```

It proves that socket.io will process `connect` first then `connection`.

Answer (score 7):

From naming:

`io.on('connection', function (socket) { });` is called directly *after* the connection has been opened.
`io.on('connect', function () { });` is called directly *before* the connection will be opened.

but on quick reading code (https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js) it looks like the event name `connect` is emitted *after* the connection has been opened and there is no event named `connection`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that clarified anything - can you exemplify it please? "connection" does exist, you can see it being used in official documentation examples.

Comment: If it exist in documentation doesn't mean it really exists. Did you test both events? When are they called?

Comment: Yes of course, noth work in different ways and I can't seem to get it.