# Socket.io - Emitted event on connect not received in client

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, ngx-socket-io

I'm using [ngx-socket-io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io) on the client in my Angular app. I've followed the setup in the "How to use" section.

I'm trying to emit an event to all connected clients when one client connects using this code:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connect', socket => {
  io.emit('foo', 'foo-event');
});
```

However the clients never receives this event when doing:

```
constructor(
  private socket: Socket
) {
  this.socket.fromEvent('foo')
    .subscribe((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
}
```

However if I change the server code to:

```
io.on('connect', socket => {

  socket.on('foo', () => {
    io.emit('foo', 'foo-event');
  });
});
```

And the client code to:

```
constructor(
  private socket: Socket
) {

  this.socket.emit('foo');

  this.socket.fromEvent('foo')
    .subscribe((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Then it works as expected.

Why can't I just emit an event and receive it on the client without emitting an event from the client first like in the second example?

Comment: did you establish a connection, before you expect to receive message?

Comment: @AakashGarg It does appear to be a timing issue.. Connection is established at root while the event is subscribed to in a feature module.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this? I may be facing a same problem, I connected to serve and I can see the response from Network in the dev tool, but not in the on('connect') callback

Comment: hi @Chrillewoodz have you guys solved this?? I am facing same issue

Comment: hi @Chi , have you solved this?

Comment: @SudhanshuGarg I can't remember, but you can check the finished code here https://github.com/chrillewoodz/war, maybe you'll find a solution. Good luck :)

Comment: I think you need to use socket instance inside io.connect for emit and listen events. In your first code you directly use io.emit instead of socket.on and you can not get socket instance for listening and sending events. So you must need to use socket instance inside io.on('connect', socket => { socket.on('foo', () => {
    io.emit('foo', 'foo-event');
  }); }

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26352045/10742959), I think you should use `connection` event instead because `connect` emits just before a successful connection. Thus you can't emit new event.